# Magento 2 Fotorama always show zoom in and out icons on fullscreen

Tags: magento2, fotorama, magnifier

How can I make it so that the zoom in and zoom out icons are always displayed, right now it only shows when zooming my browser in to 200% for the icons to show up. I see that `--disabled` gets appended to  `fotorama__zoom-in` so I tried the following:

```
.fotorama__zoom-in.fotorama__zoom-in--disabled {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Which does always show the icons, but the functionality seems to be getting disabled too, so the zoom doesn't work.

This is how it currently looks without the CSS applied:
[image]

This is how it should look with the icons there (and functional):
[image]

**So, to summarize: How can I make it so that the Zoom in and out icons always show, no matter the screensize?**

Comment: Can you share the link so i will check and give you proper solution.

Comment: I'd love to, but I can't do that unfortunately, since it is for a client and login credentials 
for the frontend are not to be shared.